# if/else function that handles PHP email user input form sanitization and validation not sanitizing

Tags: php, validation, email, xss, sanitization

I can get it to validate my email address but it isn't sanitizing it, for example when I do a simple test and input an email such as joeschm//oe@yahoo.com into the email address input field, I receive an email that says the email address is from joeschm//oe@yahoo.com.

Here is the relevant code:

```
//form validation vars
$formok = true;
$errors = array();  

//form data
$email = $_POST['email'];

//validate email address is not empty
if(empty($email)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";
//validate email address is valid
}elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
    //if email address input field is not empty and the email is valid, sanitize the email
}else{
    filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $formok = true;
}
```

Comment: RTFM: [filter_var()](http://php.net/filter_var) **RETURNS** the filtered data. You're not capturing that return value at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

You need to capture the return value of filter_var.

Comment: I consider this as the best pratice - as Netbeans tooltips shows too

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Try using that instead of your current code. It will not replace any mishaps the user puts into the email input but it will make sure it is safe to post to your database for saving.

Comment: well right now I am testing the site I am building using microsoft webmatrix running on a local host, with a Test mail server tool to test the mail function of my contact form. I am not going to be using a database at this point, although I may implement it in the future if needed. From looking at the documentation for that function it looks like I would need to implementing a mysql database